# Window close events in a winforms application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, formclosing

I am looking to prompt the user to save data when they close a form window in a winforms application. I can't figure out how to trigger the prompt to the user, should they click the red box at the top right corner of the form.

My application currently has a boolean flag, that is set to True on textchanged event. So I will only need to check for the boolean value in whatever event is trigger by the red box.

Any advice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You need to handle the [`FormClosing` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).** This event is raised just before the form is about to be closed, whether because the user clicked the "X" button in the title bar or through any other means.

Because the event is raised *before* the form is closed, it provides you with the opportunity to *cancel* the close event. You are passed an instance of the [`FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) class in the `e` parameter. By setting the [`e.Cancel` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) to True, you can cancel a pending close event.

For example:

```
Private Sub Form_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    If Not isDataSaved Then
        ' The user has unsaved data, so prompt to save
        Dim retVal As DialogResult
        retVal = MessageBox.Show("Save Changes?", YesNoCancel)
        If retVal = DialogResult.Yes Then
            ' They chose to save, so save the changes
            ' ...
        ElseIf retVal = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            ' They chose to cancel, so cancel the form closing
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
        ' (Otherwise, we just fall through and let the form continue closing)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Override OnFormClosing instead.  Pay attention to e.CloseReason.

Answer (score 5):

If you override the form's [OnFormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) method, you have the chance to notify the user that changes have been made, and the opportunity to cancel closing the form.

The event provides you with a [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx) instance which has a [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) property (which tells you why the form is closing) as well as a Cancel property, which you can set to True to stop the form from closing.

Answer (score 5):

I implent this code for C# hope so it useful to you

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {            
                base.OnFormClosing(e);
                if (PreClosingConfirmation() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Dispose(true);
                    Application.Exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }

        private DialogResult PreClosingConfirmation()
        {
            DialogResult res = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" Do you want to quit?          ", "Quit...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            return res;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) Event