# Performing some actions before closing winform application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to perform some actions after the user clicks x button but before the program exits.

Is it possible ? If yes then how can i do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851156/window-close-events-in-a-winforms-application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the form closing event

Code example VB.Net:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

End Sub
```

and c#

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Msdn => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look FormOnClosed Event of form event handlers
EXAMPLE c# CODE
 private void formname_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
                 //urcode
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can handle event FormClosing. Here it is documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx

Code sample:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
 {

    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CloseReason", e.CloseReason );
    messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Cancel", e.Cancel );
    messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "FormClosing Event" );
}
```