# No overload for 'FormClosed' matches delegate FormClosedEventHandler

Tags: c#

I have a Form..I want before the User close form..my form show Dialog box(Yes/no).If user press yes button the form exit and if press no don't close.but my program shows error

> No overload for 'FormClosed' matches delegate FormClosedEventHandler

So I tried out some codes But the problem is not resolved.

Thanks for any feedback.

my code is :

```
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult closeMainForm = MessageBox.Show("you want close ?", "My Program", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (closeMainForm == DialogResult.Yes)
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
        if (closeMainForm == DialogResult.No) { e.Cancel = true; this.Activate(); }
```

Comment: Did you looked at formclosing event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window close events in a winforms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851156/window-close-events-in-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FormClosingEventArgs` as the type of your `e` parameter, use `FormClosedEventArgs`.

But, I guess it's more convenient if you don't use the `FormClosed` event, use `FormClosing` event instead.

Basically, you want to execute your this before closing the form, if you use `FormClosed`, it will only be executed when the form is actually closed. So use `FormClosing` as your event

Hope it helps