# How can I make a Winforms form terminate the application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, terminate

I am coding Winforms in C#. I want to set up my program so that if a form is closed, the program will terminate or stop. I already know how to select a form that will be opened first.

This is the code in my program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MainMenu
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set up my login.cs form so that if that form is closed, the program will terminate. Is this possible?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something when a form is closed, you need to [handle the FormClosing event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851228/6471538). Within your event handler, call `Application.Exit()` to terminate the application.

Using the model in the answer linked above (but in C#), use this event handler:

```
private void Form_Closing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

To add the handler, simply register the method to the event as such in your form class (based on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bdee708-db4b-4e46-a99c-99726fa25cfb/how-do-i-add-formclosing-event?forum=csharpgeneral) discussion from MSDN):

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form_Closing);
```